# Object is possibly "null" - error with TypeScript linter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tslint

I have a question about TypeScript! We're doing a JSX to TypeScript conversion across our projects.

```
  {instances.map(instance => {
    const { id, name, type } = second;

    const pageUrl = makePath(
      routes.page.path,
      { firstId: first.id , secondId: id }, <<<<<<
    );
```

On the line with "<<<<<<", "first" of "first.id" is highlighted with the following error:

```
Object is possibly 'null'.
```

I'm unsure how to define it to where it wouldn't be considered null. I was able to figure out the second one through destructuring, but you can't define "id" twice. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: There isn't enough context in your question to provide an answer. Could you please include more of the surrounding code and especially include something that does not produce the error here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEHcAsEMBdQJYGdEDsm2qgxgUyQPwCwAUAupjvgHQC20ADgBTkZZ6gC8AfKAN6lQQ0CAgx4yUElzYA9qgAmxEsNByK-RAoA0oVNFq5dsAJ4NcoAL5cpM+QoDcg4aKhxEKegGsLDOJGVVdQxQPwBzXABVACcAGxtvXAAFfyZnVVdxD1Bo2QBXWHxA1Rz8wqRqcNxK-210lzA3CRQAMwRojGLVPlA2jtgASQUALl72jGoEBVBdaXUFIdGpq11RAB4NzfqASicSS22gA

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work if I define earlier in the component,

```
  const firstId = (first ? first.id : '');
```

and replace `firstId: first.id` with `firstId: firstId`.

If this isn't a recommended solution, please let me know! However, it does resolve the error I was seeing and it doesn't seem to impact functionality at all.

Answer (score 0):

The type checker is unable to determine if `first` will ever be non `null`.
You can add a [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) `!` directly after the object in question to tell the linter that it will not be null, try this:

```
{ firstId: first!.id , secondId: id }, <<<<<<
```